# Facing problem while connecting SSMS server

Tags: sql-server

@sql-server Team,

We are facing a problem while connecting to SSMS Server from Azure Data factory pipeline activity/dataset.
We are not sure to put exact format of - server_name, database_name , user_name, and authentication_type.

Can you please help us to frame the proper inputs for above mentioned 4 fields?

Comment: [ConnectionStrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) ftw maybe?

Answer (score 1):

There is no SSMS server. I assume you mean SQL Server. Further that you mean the on-prem product as Azure SQL database is different.

The UI is just a wrapper for constructing a connection string. If you're familiar with those switch to the JSON view and edit it directly.

For server name give the SQL Server instance name. Ask your DBA for this. The integration runtime you choose to use must have network access to this instance. Your sysadmins will work that out.

Database name is exactly what you would put in a CREATE DATABSE statement if you were to re-create this DB.

SQL Server supports different [authentication methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/choose-an-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-ver16). Choose the one your DBA has configured.

Likely a specific user id will have been created just for ADF. This user id must be granted the usual privileges in SQL Server.

Best not to put the password directly in ADT linked service configuration. Create an Azure Key Vault for your organisation and configure the linked service to pull the password from there.